# UMVUE and MLE of one Normally distributed variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I'd like to ask for help on solving the following problem - I believe I solved the first part but I'm not sure how to proceed with the rest:

Let $X$ be an observation from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance 1. Find the UMVUE of $μ^2$ and the UMVUE of $P[|X| > 1]$. Compare these with the MLE’s of these parameters.

I started by identifying that $f_X(x)$ is part of the exponential family and thus X is a complete and sufficient statistic for $\mu$. Further, I found that $E[X^2] = 1+ \mu^2$ and so $X^2-1$ is an unbiased estimator for $\mu^2$ and a function of our complete and sufficient statistic. Therefore, $X^2-1$ is the UMVUE of $\mu^2$.

I am not sure how to find the UMVUE for $P[|X| > 1]$ and compare them with the MLEs.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: An obvious unbiased estimator of $P[|X| > 1]$ is the indicator variable $\mathbf 1_{|X>1|}$

Comment: MLE of $\mu$ is obviously $X$ and $P(|X|>1)$ is a function of $\mu$ so use invariance property for its MLE.

Comment: @StubbornAtom To find the MLE of $P(|X|>1)$ I feel like I need to evaluate the integral, however, I can do so in terms of CDF:  $P(|X|>1) = 1 - P(|X|<1)= 1 - P(-1<X<1) = 1 - P(-1-\mu < X-\mu < 1-\mu) = 1 - (F_Z(1-\mu) - F_Z(-1-\mu))$, where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. I was expecting a more explicit answer in terms of $\mu_{MLE} = X$ for this MLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set the following estimator T for $\mathbb{P}[|X|>1]$

$$T=\mathbb{1}_{|X|>1}= 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $\mathbb{P}[|X|\leq1]$} \\
1, & \text{if $\mathbb{P}[|X|>1]$ }
\end{cases}$$

Obviously $\mathbb{E}[T]=\mathbb{P}[|X|>1]$

Then T is unbiased and function of a CSS.

In order to get the MLE you can use invariance property